# Shell script not running with the input of a text file

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

I am solving something using mapper shell script. I have created two files

```
mr_test.txt
```

we will see how map reduce works for word count problem. word count is considered as hello world of map reduce programming. this program will not print hello world instead it will give word counts. lets see map reduce in action.

and another shell script called

mapper.sh

```
while read line; do
  for token in $line; do
    if ["$token" = "hello" ]; then 
      echo "hello,1"
    elif ["$token" = "world"]; then 
      echo "world,1"
    fi
  done
done
```

I am looking out here to print all the hello and world present in my txt document using the shell script.
Now I enter the following commands

```
chmod +x mapper.sh
```

later followed by

```
cat mr_test.txt | ./mapper.sh
```

I get the output as

```
./mapper.sh: line 5: [hello: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [hello: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: $'[everyone,\r': command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: $'[everyone,\r': command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [we: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [we: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [will: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [will: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [see: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [see: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [how: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [how: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [map: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [map: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [reduce: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [reduce: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [works: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [works: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [for: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [for: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [word: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [word: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [count: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [count: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [problem.: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [problem.: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [word: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [word: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [count: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [count: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [is: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [is: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [considered: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [considered: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [as: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [as: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [hello: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [hello: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [world: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [world: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [of: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [of: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [map: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [map: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [reduce: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [reduce: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [programming.: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [programming.: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [this: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [this: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [program: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [program: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [will: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [will: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [not: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [not: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [print: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [print: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [hello: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [hello: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [world: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [world: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [instead: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [instead: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [it: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [it: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [will: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [will: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [give: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [give: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [word: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [word: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [counts.: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [counts.: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [lets: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [lets: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [see: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [see: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [map: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [map: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [reduce: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [reduce: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: [in: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: [in: command not found
./mapper.sh: line 5: $'[action.\r': command not found
./mapper.sh: line 8: $'[action.\r': command not found
```

I have checked a lot of places for incorrect syntax however cannot narrow down as to what is going wrong.

Comment: put your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/# it will tell errors

Comment: Your reading just the text file right? in that case, just stdin the file like ./mapper.sh < mr_test.txt. Still, you have errors in your shell script that needs to be corrected.

Comment: The syntax of an `if` statement is `if` *command*, the brackets are not part of conditional syntax (unlike many other languages).  The single `[` is actually the `test` command (do a `type [`).  As you know, whitespace must separate commands in a shell language, therefore there should be whitespace between the `if` and the `[` command, and whitespace between `[` and arguments passed to it.

Comment: Useless use of cat award ?  ./mapper.sh < mr_test.txt .   http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 1):

To avoid spaces problems among "read line" use while in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
CNT=0
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "hello world" ]]; then
        CNT=$(( $CNT + 1 ))
    fi  
done < $1

echo "File '$1' has $CNT times the 'hello world' phrase"
```

To run the script, pass your wordfile as a parameter, like that:
   
 ./mapper.sh mr_test.txt

Answer (score 0):

`[` is not part of the shell grammar, but is a command.  The problem is more obvious is you spell it `test`.  (The only difference between the command `test` and the command `[` is that `[` requires that its last argument be `]`).

`if [ "$token" = "hello" ]` is semantically the same as `if test "$token" = hello`.  It should be obvious that `if test"$token" = hello` is an error, which ought to make it clear why `if ["$token" = hello ]` is an error.

Note that quoting rules are important, and perhaps it needs to be made explicit that `if test"$token"` is treated exactly the same as `if "test$token"`.

For this particular script, you're better off using a case statement:

```
while read line; do
  for token in $line; do
    case $token in
    hello) echo hello,1;;
    world) echo world,1;;
    esac
  done
done
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you. Shell is touchy about spaces - especially around "[" which is not considered a square bracket but a condition check.

```
while read line;
do
        for token in $line
        do
                if [ $token = "hello" ]; then
                        echo "Hello,1"
                elif [ $token = "world" ]; then
                        echo "world,1"
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: No, `[` is not a "condition check".  It is a command.  It is more clear if you spell it "test" and write `if test "$token" = hello;`

Comment: Consider `[[` for better tests.